# Kotlin-android unresolved reference : queue

Tags: android, kotlin

I  imported retrofi2.Callback
and I still get this error unresolved reference: enqueue
this is the code of the login class

```
  import android.content.Intent
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.provider.ContactsContract
  import android.widget.Button
  import android.widget.EditText
  import android.widget.TextView
  import android.widget.Toast
  import com.cbmis.imageapp.Common.Common
  import com.cbmis.imageapp.Model.APIResponse
  import com.cbmis.imageapp.Remote.IMyAPI
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
  import retrofit2.Call
  import retrofit2.Callback
  import retrofit2.Response
```

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
 internal lateinit var mService:IMyAPI
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    //initservice
    mService = Common.api

    //Event
 txtregister.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity,RegisterActivity::class.java))
 finish()
 }
  btn_login.setOnClickListener { authentificateUser(findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email).text.toString(), findViewById<TextView>(R.id.password).text.toString()) }

    }



private fun authentificateUser(email: String, password: String) {

    mService.loginUser(email, password)
            .enqueue(object :Callback<APIResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<APIResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                   Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,t!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<APIResponse>?, response: Response<APIResponse>?) {
                    if (response!!.body()!!.error)
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,response!!.body()!!.errr_msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Login Success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

         })
}
```

}

and this is the interface/

```
interface IMyAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("signup.php")
fun registerUser(@Field("email") email:String,@Field("name")name:String,@Field("password") password:String,@Field("dateofbirth") dateofbirth:String,@Field("genderM") genderM:String,@Field("genderF") genderF:String):Class<APIResponse>

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login.php")
fun loginUser(@Field("email") email:String,@Field("password") password:String):Class<APIResponse>
```

}

Any solutions can be proposed to solve this problem

Comment: First, you should post your code as text instead of an image. Second, could you show the declaration of the `loginUser` method?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 3):

You should be returning a Retrofit [`Call`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html) from your API's functions:

```
interface IMyAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("signup.php")
    fun registerUser(/* params */) : Call<APIResponse>


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login.php")
    fun loginUser(/* params */): Call<APIResponse>

}
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention